# Why would someone initialize a variable with long.MinValue or long.MaxValue?

Tags: c#

Recently reviewing some code, I (yes, for the first time) ran across someone initializing a long as something other than what I was accustomed to...

```
var thisId = long.minValue
```

I realize that the value of this constant is negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808; that is, hexadecimal 0x8000000000000000. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.minvalue.aspx)

The programmer actually returns this number if certain conditions are not met and within his logic uses comparison logic to test thisId == long.minValue.

My first thought was that this causes more overhead than if one was to initialize the variable with ZERO or NULL...but I get there could be a case where you can't have a nullable long and that there could be a ZERO for a value.

So, is there any drawback to using this technique when initializing a variable with long.MinValue or long.MaxValue?

Comment: Well, only that `MinValue` could be a valid value too...

Comment: Looks like the developer was using `MinValue` as a magic value and simply relying on it being *less likely* that a valid calculation would result in `MinValue` than in a zero.  It's not a good practice, but it's certainly not uncommon.

Comment: Actually .NET FW does this as well - for example HttpCache makes use of DateTime.MaxValue when determining sliding or absolute exipration.

Comment: `long.MinValue` and `long.MaxValue` are constant values and produce the same IL instructions as setting the variable to 0, for instance, so there isn't actually more overhead.

Comment: constants are constant

Comment: Hence ``long.MinValue`` could usually be also a valid value it would make sense to return a ``long?`` and use ``null`` as an unset state or write code that uses a TryXxxx-pattern to indicate that something went wrong or throw exceptions. Relying on magic numbers is bad design in my opinion.

Comment: @JonSkeet there's really no way we could have an id < 0 at all...it couldn't even be -1...which is why I furrowed my brows at -9,223,372,036,854,775,808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is, it depends (as usual.)

If I approach the problem generically,

```
T SomeFunction<T>()
{
    var result = default(T);

    //// do "some stuff"

    return result;
}
```

now, when would the default be incorrect? I can think of two reasons,

1. `some stuff` is conditional so I've optimised my code to save an `else`
2. the default of `T` is a valid result of performing `some stuff`, so I need to distinguish.

---

In relation to the other aspect of your question, There is no detriment to performance using a constant over literal or default.

Comment: good general response and, most importantly, your comment about there being no detriment to performance is the answer to my core question...thanks. +1 for Jodrell

Answer (score 4):

It is a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value), guaranteed to be wrong if the rest of the code doesn't come up with a better value.  Similar to Double.NaN.

The approach is okayish for a *long*, gets in the danger-zone for an *int*.  I personally never do this and favor a bool or a nullable, guaranteed to never cause an accident that way.  And more readable.  Or just 0 of course, but can only work if a valid value is guaranteed to be non-zero.

Comment: Why the distinguishment between `int` and `long`?

Comment: It is a 2*32 distinguishment.  Four billion times lower odds that the data matches the sentinel value.

Comment: I am not such a big gambler I would bet on that.

Comment: int is a int32 and long is int64...that's it...on the feedback, I would go for the long? as well.

Comment: would this actually qualify as a 'sentinal' value? Seems like your link defines one as more of a list ender or loop termination condition.

Comment: Well, there's more than one use.  In this case it fits the "rogue" or "signal" value usage.  Although not supported in .NET, Double.NaN can have multiple values on the processor.  There are signaling (sNaN) and quiet (qNaN) values :)

Answer (score 2):

Why does someone initialize it with `long.MinValue`? Because it indicates some special state. What that state is, depends on the context. For example to make clear it 'doesn't have a value'.

Personally I would use a `long?` (a nullable `long`) for these cases, since that makes the state of the variable much clearer.

The drawback of the use of `long.MinValue` in my opinion is that it on itself doesn't indicate a state very well. It is error prone and usually only the programmer who wrote it knows the meaning of it.

Comment: This is how I was feeling before posting this...but wanted the feedback. I would usually go for long? as well.

Comment: Agree it is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if `long.MinValue` is a valid return value for the method or not. If `long.MinValue` is not a valid value for return type and is only used to signal a 'not found' return value, it's better to use a nullable long as return type.

The downside of using a value(e.g. 0 or `long.MinValue`) instead of null in these circumstances is introduction of magic numbers. It makes the code harder to understand and more error prone. For example, consider this method:

```
public int Min(int[] ints);
```

What if this method returns int.MinValue ? Is it valid or not ?

Or consider the `String.IndexOf` method. It returns -1 if the passed value is not found within the string. Although it's not that hard to guess that -1 means not found, it still introduces the magic number -1 in your code and thus makes it harder to read. I think that `String.IndexOf` method is only kept this way for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Typical use case for `Long.MinValue` would be finding a maximum value in the range. It's good as a starting condition. In a loop you can then do `if(currentValue > maxValue) maxValue =  currentValue;` If you assign `maxValue` to a 0 at the start, there could be negative values only, and out of -10, -5 and -1, you will never get to a -1, for example.